# Define a Makefile variable using a ENV variable or a default value

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, environment-variables

I am trying to do a simple thing:

```
TMPDIR ?= /tmp

test:
    @echo $(TMPDIR)
```

This works if I run:

```
$ make test
/tmp
```

It also works if I run:

```
$ make test -e TMPDIR=~/tmp
/home/user/tmp
```

What can I do to also have it works for:

```
$ TMPDIR=~/tmp make test
/home/user/tmp
```

Comment: Erhm... what you have DOES work (if you use `?=` and you have an environment variable set, then the value of the environment variable will be used instead).  What exactly is the problem (why do you think it doesn't work)?

Comment: Also just FYI, adding quotes to variable values inside a makefile is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Yes I double checked and I works with `TMPDIR ?= "/tmp"` and `echo $(TMPDIR)` the only thing is not to forget the parenthesis around the variable name.

Comment: Quotes around the value to assign in the makefile itself are not necessary and in fact are not generall correct, as @MadScientist says. You do want quotes (likely single) around the **use** of the variable in a body line though.

Comment: You have your uses of `-e` backwards. `-e` says to allow env vars to **override** variables defined in the makefile, they don't affect variable assignment coming from command line arguments.

Comment: Sorry Natim, but `?=` _does_ work.  If it's not doing what you want then either your explanation above is confusing and we're not understanding what you want, or there's something about your real environment which is not reflected in your question above.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

To follow up on my comments above, here's an example:

```
T ?= foo
all:
        $(info T is $(T))
```

Now if I run the Makefile in various ways, it behaves as we expect (I get `foo` only if I don't set `T` either on the command line or environment):

```
$ make
T is foo

$ make T=bar
T is bar

$ T=bar make
T is bar
```

Comment: What is this: `all:;:`?

Comment: `all:` creates a rule for a target _all_.  The semicolon ends the list of prerequisites and starts the first recipe line.  The last `:` is the recipe; a colon is a special POSIX shell operator that means, basically, "do nothing".  So this defines a full rule for the `all` target which has a recipe that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I actually prefer the original format because it works without having to convert spaces to tabs (it's hard to put a hard TAB into an example in SO).  But I guess other people approved the edit so...

Answer (score 64):

[Variables specified on `make` command line override the values assigned in makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding):

```
TMPDIR := "/tmp"
test:
    @echo $(TMPDIR)
```

And then:

```
make TMPDIR=whatever
whatever
```

It is generally considered a bad practice for makefiles to depend on environment variables because that may lead to non-reproducible builds. This is why passing variable overrides in `make` command line explicitly is recommended.

Comment: Ok that's good to know but how can I use the environment variable as a default value if set?

Comment: In that specific case TMPDIR is a variable that could exists and that I want to use if it does.

Comment: I tried `TMPDIR := $(or $$TMPDIR,$$TMPDIR,"/tmp")` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Natim Why do you put extra dollar signs?

Comment: Seems like these `$(or` invocations are more than are needed.  Doesn't this work? `$(or $X,abc)`  ?

Comment: If the variable name is more than one character, the parentheses are needed: incorrect: `$(or $TMPDIR, /tmp)` ; correct: `$(or $(TMPDIR), /tmp)`.  That's what @Natim was trying to fix.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin:  
Can you please explain differences between `${x}` and `$(x)` and when do we need in makefile to use `$${x} or $$(x)`

Comment: @JavaSa No difference in gnu make between the two.

Comment: ${x} is expanded earlier in the make-cycles than $${x}

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple solution:

```
SHELL  := env TMPDIR=$(TMPDIR) $(SHELL)
TMPDIR ?= "/tmp"

all:
  @echo $(TMPDIR)
```

which works for both scenarios: `TMPDIR=new/path make` and `make TMPDIR=new/path`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the thing you could do is:

```
TMPDIR := "/tmp"

ifdef $$TMPDIR
TMPDIR := $$TMPDIR
endif

test:
    echo $(TMPDIR)
```

Comment: It doesn't work as `TMPDIR=~/tmp make`, only when running as `make TMPDIR=~/tmp `, but the question was to make it work for both.